# Issue with dynamic rendering a select box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I'm dynamically creating a select node with option nodes inside. The code works fine in FF & IE8.

But it refuses to work in IE8 in quirks mode or ie7 compatibility mode. And it refuses to work in IE6.

The option nodes do get added to the DOM.

```
var PersonnelSelectorListBox,
    PersonnelSelectorDiv;

function AddListItems() {
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        $('<option />').text('Item ' + i).appendTo(PersonnelSelectorListBox);
    }
}

PersonnelSelectorDiv = $("<div>").css({
    position: "relative", 
    display: 'block', 
    top: 20,
    zIndex: 2
});

$("#AddToList").after(PersonnelSelectorDiv);

$("#AddToList").click(function() {
    //alert("click");
    AddListItems();
});

PersonnelSelectorListBox = $("<select id=\"PLB\" size=\"15\">").attr({
    size: 15, 
    id: 'PLB'
}).width(200);

PersonnelSelectorDiv.append(PersonnelSelectorListBox);
```

Example code is http://jsfiddle.net/jKmh4/3/

Does anyone know how to trick ie into rerendering part of the DOM ?

The issue is with calling the AddListItems function via a click event rather then calling it directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The option nodes do get added to the DOM.

Yeah, it's definitely a rendering bug.  The only real workaround I could find was to hide the option box and show it again, after adding the `<option>` elements:

```
PersonnelSelectorListBox.hide().show();
```

This forces the browser to re-render the content properly.

**http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/jKmh4/4/**

Comment: I was looking for a way to rerender the dom. .hide().show() so easy.

Comment: I had a similar issue with dynamically added selects in IE9, after dynamically changing their options: I could select the new options with the cursor keys, but the dropdown still displayed the old options. `hide().show()` finally fixed it for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Only this worked for me with IE 9. All other solutions on SO did not do the trick (mostly, because I'm not using selectmenu, but a standard select element).